# Varien_File_Csv_Multy Class Not Found

Tags: magento-1.8, csv

I am trying to instantiate the class `Varien_File_Csv_Multy` which is located in

> lib/Varien/File/CsvMulty.php

```
$csv= new Varien_File_Csv_Multy();
echo get_class($csv);
```

and

```
$csv= new Varien_File_CsvMulty();
 echo get_class($csv);
```

Its throwing error  Fatal error: Class `'Varien_File_Csv_Multy'` not found

I want to know how to add I access the methods of the class.Is this class used in Magento core code anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is not autoloaded because it does not follow the standard class name => path relation.
So the class name is `Varien_File_Csv_Multy` but the file name is `Varien/File/CsvMulty.php`.
It would be autoloaded if the file name would be `Varien/File/Csv/Multy.php` or if the class name would be `Varien_File_CsvMulty`.
The only solution I see is to include the file before instantiating the class.

```
require_once 'Varien/File/CsvMulty.php';
$csv= new Varien_File_Csv_Multy();
```

Comment: Does the autoload.php in Magento also work for non module files - meaning files that are in a library like the above one and not part of the module directory structure?

Comment: @ParasSood. Yes the autoloader works for the `lib` folder also, but it looks for the class file following the same path. Replace `_` with `/` and add `.php`. But in this case you get the wrong filename. See my explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the fatal error because that class is not visible to the PHP engine since it's source file is not included. A simple fix would be to include it in the file you are trying to instantiate the class in.

Did a grep on the code base and didn't find Varien_File_Csv_Multy being called anywhere.